# Conditional probability. Where is the error?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, conditional-probability, solution-verification, markov-process

Let $\eta_t$ be a Markov process defined in a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ and taking values in $[0,1]$.

Call $\rho=\inf\{t\geq 0 :\eta_t\geq 1/2\}$ and $S=\inf\{t\geq \rho: \eta_t=0\}$.

Let $A\in F$ be a measurable set such that $P(A)>0$ and $$P(\rho<\infty|A)=1.$$
Calling $F_t=\sigma(\eta_s, s\in [0, t])$ the sigma algebra generated by the process up to time $t$, is that true the following equality?

\begin{align}P(S<\infty|A)&=E(\mathbb I_{\{S<\infty\}}|A)\\
&=E(E(I_{\{S<\infty\}}|F_{\rho}, \rho<+\infty, A)|A)\\
&=E(I_{\{S<\infty\}}|F_{\rho}, \rho<+\infty, A)E(1|A)\\
&=E(I_{\{S<\infty\}}|F_{\rho}, \rho<+\infty, A)\\
&=P(S<\infty|F_{\rho}, \rho<+\infty, A).
\end{align}
I guess there is an error in my argument. Where I am wrong?